# Having two lists as a value to a single key: Dictionaries

Tags: python

Looking for a way to add two lists to a value in a dictionary for example if want to add two lists to a single value for example

For example this dictionary `dict1 = {a: [], b:[], c:[]}`

Would become `dict1 = {a:([1,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4]),b:[],c:[]}`

When you add the two lists `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `[1,2,3,4]` to the key `a`.
And if you were to print the key `a` you would get the two lists as output

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Why did the value of `a` change into a tuple "`()`"? `a:([1,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4])`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `list.append()` because your `dict1['a']`'s value is a `list`. See this example:

```
dict1 = {'a': [], 'b':[], 'c':[]}

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [1,2,3,4]

dict1['a'].append(a)
dict1['a'].append(b)

print(dict1)
```

Output:

```
{'a': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4]], 'b': [], 'c': []}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also doing it in this way by adding two list `[a]+[b]`

**Edit:**  from the comment. Another better way `[a,b]`

```
dict1 = {'a': [], 'b':[], 'c':[]}
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = ['a','b']
dict1['a']=[a]+[b]
print(dict1)
```

Comment: Or better, `[a, b]`.

Comment: @ChihebNexus, yes that's another better one :) .